# How to assign values to const char* array and print to screen

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

Although I am using C++, as a requirement I need to use const char* arrays instead of string or char arrays. Since I am new, I am required to learn about how to use const char*. I have declared my const char* array as `const char* str[5]`. At a later point in the program I need to populate each on of the 5 elements with values.

However, if I try to assign a value like this:

```
const char* str[5];
char value[5];
value[0] = "hello";
str[0] = value[0];
```

It will not compile. What is the proper way to add a char array to char to a const char* array and then print the array? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just curiosity, what is the significance of `const char* str[5];` rather than just `char* str[5];`?

Comment: You seem mixed up. `char value[5]` is an array of 5 characters. `value[0]` is a single character out of those 5. How do you expect a single character to hold the value `"hello"` ?

Comment: @RafafTahsin  Significance here in this question  or in general ?

Comment: mostly here in this question. what is the significance of using `const char* str[5];` here? and for general purpose, so far I know, the significance of `const char* str[5];` is that it's a variable pointer which points to a `const` variable. Does it have any other significances? >>> @ameyCU

Comment: It's not bad to learn naked pointer logic, but it _is_ a good thing to define your concepts: `typedef const char* MyString; MyString strings[5];`  This will for sure help avoiding mistakes.

Comment: In C, _string_ is not a type, nor a `char *`, nor a pointer.  A _string_ is a character array up to and including a terminating  null character `'\0'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The string `"hello"` is made up of 6 characters, not 5.

   ```
   {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}
   ```
2. If you assign the string when you declare `value`, your code can look similar to what your currently have:

   ```
   char value[6] = "hello";
   ```
3. If you want to do it in two separate lines, you should use `strncpy()`.

   ```
   char value[6];
   strncpy(value, "hello", sizeof(value));
   ```
4. To place a pointer to `value` in the list of strings named `str`:

   ```
   const char * str[5];
   char value[6] = "hello";
   str[0] = value;
   ```

   Note that this leaves `str[1]` through `str[4]` with unspecified values.

Comment: How about `char value[] = "hello";`?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Sure. But it's not obvious to revolution how many bytes that occupies.

Comment: @BillLynch, your last example `str[0] = value;` seems very dangerous. It assigns _4 byte pointer address_ value to _1 byte char value_ place.

Comment: `str` in this example is a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Various methods to populate `const char* str[5]` later point in the program.

```
int main(void) {
  const char* str[5];

  str[0] = "He" "llo";  // He llo are string literals that concat into 1

  char Planet[] = "Earth";  
  str[1] = Planet;  // OK to assign a char * to const char *, but not visa-versa

  const char Greet[] = "How";
  str[2] = Greet;

  char buf[4];
  buf[0] = 'R'; // For a character array to qualify as a string, need a null character.  
  buf[1] = 0;   // '\0' same _value_ as 0  
  str[3] = buf; // array buf converts to address of first element: char *

  str[4] = NULL; // Do not want to print this.

  for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    puts(str[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

.

```
Hello  
Earth  
How  
R
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value[0] = "hello";
```

How can this hold "hello". It can hold only one character.

Also `value[5]` is not enough for this . There will be no space for `'\0'` and program will exhibit **UB**.

Thus either use `value[6]` -

```
char value[6];
strncpy(value,"hello",sizeof value);
```

Or declare like this -

```
char value[]="hello";
```

And after that just make the pointer point to this array. Something like this-

```
str[0]=value;
```